# Is "he be let off the hook" a complete sentence?

Tags: word-in-context

From this [article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/jimmy-fallon-donald-trump_us_57dbecd4e4b0071a6e06801e),

> Fallon is not Letterman, and he never will be, nor does he seem to
>   want to be. **But that doesn’t mean he be let off the hook** for
>   humanizing a well-documented xenophobic, racist and misogynistic
>   serial liar, which is exactly what he did on Thursday.

Doesn't the absence of a *should* after *he* in the phrase, "he be let off the hook", make it sound incomplete?

Shouldn't there be a *should*, making it sound *But that doesn't mean he should be let off the hook*?

Comment: It's a typographical error. "Should" or "can" was omitted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a typographical error.

Comment: I don't have an example off-hand, but I think there is some dialect or regional style that uses this kind of phrasing.

Comment: @user3169 If you're hunting for the subjunctive here, you might as well be hunting snipe, I think.